# delete files from azure data lake gen2 which are x days old

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a requirement to delete parquet files (suffixed with date) from azure data lake storage gen2 using databricks notebooks. The files which are 'x' days old should be deleted.can someone help me with this requirement

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you want to be super, super super careful with deletes.  Make sure you fully test and delete logic before faithfully relying on it.  Having said that, it's probably best to list all files, so you know what you have in your inventory, and then start the delete process.  Something like this should do it for you.

List Files:

```
# Python
from azure.storage.blob import BlobBlockService

blob_block_service = BlobBlockService(account_name = 'your_account_name', account_key = 'you_account_key')

generator = blob_block_service.list_blobs('rawdata')
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob Name: " + blob.name)


##############################################################################
# using prefix
from azure.storage.blob import BlobBlockService

blob_block_service = BlobBlockService(account_name = 'your_account_name', account_key = 'you_account_key')

generator = blob_block_service.list_blobs('rawdata', prefix = '2020/01/01/')
for blob in generator:
    print("\t Blob Name: " + blob.name)
```

Delete Files (BE VERY CAREFUL HERE):

```
import os
import glob

# get a recursive list of file paths that matches pattern including sub directories
fileList = glob.glob('/rawdata/your_path_here/**/*.txt', recursive=True)

# Iterate over the list of filepaths & remove each file.
for filePath in fileList:
    try:
        os.remove(filePath)
    except OSError:
        print("Error while deleting file")
```

See this link for more info.

https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-remove-files-by-matching-pattern-wildcards-certain-extensions-only/